# Usar select top para declarar uma variavel

Tags: c#, sql-server

Eu queria atribuir o valor do último item cadastrado na tabela `alu_cod`, mas o query me retorna erro após o `@total =`:

```sql
declare @total int
select @total = SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Alunos ORDER BY 
Alu_COD DESC  
select @total
```

Answer (score 2):

A sua sintaxe está incorrecta. Pode atribuir o valor de um SELECT a uma variável da seguinte forma:

Usando SELECT:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @total = Alu_COD 
  FROM Alunos 
 ORDER BY Alu_COD DESC  
SELECT @total
```

Usando SET

```
SET @total= (SELECT TOP 1 Alu_COD 
               FROM Alunos 
              ORDER BY Alu_COD DESC )
SELECT @total
```

**Atenção** ao usar a primeira alternativa. Caso a sua query retorne mais do que um registo (não é o caso aqui, por estar a usar o TOP), esta alternativa irá atribuir à variável o último registo que for devolvido pela query, sem mostrar qualquer mensagem de erro (isto pode originar bugs na sua aplicação/script). Já a segunda alternativa, usando o SET, nas mesmas circunstâncias irá mostrar uma mensagem de erro.

Em cima estão exemplos em como atribuir o valor de uma única coluna a uma varável, caso queira selecionar o registo completo, tem que definir uma variável por cada coluna no SELECT ou, preferencialmente, definir uma TABLE VARIABLE.

Usando uma table variable

```
DECLARE @alunos TABLE (
  Alu_COD  int,
  Alu_NOME VARCHAR(50),
  Alu_DATA_REGISTO DATE
)
INSERT INTO @alunos (Alu_COD, Alu_NOME, Alu_DATA)
SELECT TOP 1 Alu_COD, Alu_NOME, Alu_DATA
  FROM Alunos 
 ORDER BY Alu_COD DESC
```

Definindo as variáveis individualmente

```
DECLARE @Alu_COD  int,
        @Alu_NOME VARCHAR(50),
        @Alu_DATA_REGISTO DATE

SELECT TOP 1 @Alu_COD = Alu_COD,
       @Alu_NOME = Alu_NOME,
       @Alu_DATA_REGISTO = Alu_DATA_REGISTO
  FROM Alunos
 ORDER BY Alu_COD DESC
```